# Login to Facebook on iOS using virtual keyboard

Tags: ios, facebook

I'm writing an iPad app, which requires the iPad to be plugged into a scanning device. The scanning device seems to be acting as a hardware keyboard, as anytime the device is plugged in to the iPad, the software keyboard disappears off screen. To get around this, I created a virtual keyboard of my own. This is all working fine.

However, now I need to offer the ability to login to Facebook. Obviously Single Sign-On is not an option, as this switches over to the Facebook app which does not have my virtual keyboard. What are my other options? I haven't tried it yet as this app is still in planning phase, but I'm not that confident that I'll be able to insert text into the in-app dialog. Is the in-app dialog even an option with the latest SDK? It doesn't seem like Facebook provides a straight login API, either?

Note: unplugging the scanning device temporarily is not an option.

Comment: Single Sign-On in the *next* version of iOS will not switch you over to the app. Will not help you right now, but it will down the road.

Comment: I believe this is an app for internal use only, so I could possibly limit to the next version of iOS. Not sure if we're allowed to talk about the specifics of how that would work, yet?